# Image generated by GET parameters. How do I force facebook sharer to clear cache before sharing image?

Tags: php, facebook

I am generating an image based off of GET parameters in the url, combining them, then sharing that image in the facebook sharer. However, facebook seems to cache the image unless I manually clear the cache in the debugger tool.

I need a way to clear facebook's cache before sharing. Is this possible?

In this example, I'm hardcoding the GET parameters, but in the real thing it will be based off of selected options.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $img1= 'images/img1.png'; 
    $img2 = 'images/img2.png';  

    $query = 'img1=';
    $query .= $img1;
    $query .= '&img2=';
    $query .= $img2;
?>


    <!--facebook meta-->
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsite.com/mergePhotos.php?<?php echo $query;?>" />  
    <meta property="og:title" content="This is my website"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="123456789" />
    <meta property="og:type"   content="website" /> 
    <meta property="og:url"    content="http://mywebsite.com/mergePhotos.php?<?php echo $query;?>" /> 
    <meta property="og:description"    content="Look at these images I combined!" />
```

**mergePhotos.php:**

```
 <?php

        $imgl = $_GET['img1'];
        $img2 = $_GET['img2'];

        // Create image instances
        $dest = imagecreatefrompng($imgl);
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($img2);
        imagecolortransparent($src, imagecolorat($src, 0, 0));

        // Copy and merge
        $src_x = imagesx($src);
        $src_y = imagesy($src);
        imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, 100);

        // Output and free from memory
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($dest);

        imagedestroy($dest);
        imagedestroy($src);
    ?>
```

Comment: put a cache-buster value into the url? e.g. `'script.php?foo=' . microtime(TRUE);`? That'll make each url look unique and keep farcebook from caching it.

Comment: Does the cache-buster have to do with the "?foo=" part or the "microtime(TRUE)" part?  What is the microtime?

Comment: mostly the microtime bit. it'll add a number that's different every time, so each url looks unique. e.g. `script.php?foo=123.456` and then `script.php?foo=123.457`, etc...

Comment: It seems to be caching the page by ignoring the query parameters. I'm fine if it caches script.php?foo=123 but when I change the query to script.php?foo=456 then it still displays the image as if foo=123.  It will only pull the new query parameters when I manually force a clear from the debugger.

Comment: I like your suggestion though, I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: any ideas? It seems like a unique url should force a cache clear, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add the microtime (per Marc B's suggestion) to the end of the facebook sharer code. So the way my code was structured was that the fb-sharer code was on one page, and it was referencing the metadata on another page.  When I add the microcode query to the end of the sharer code, facebook forces a refresh.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://mywebsite.com/facebookMeta.php?<?php echo(microtime());?>" >  </div>
```